# Where and how are procedure and packages store or saved in oracle database? Do oracle store compiled version separately?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

in plsql when I create and compile a procedure, whether inside a package or standalone, how specification and body of procedure is saved in database?

Answer (score 4):

Like all the other data about objects etc, the text of the code is stored in the dictionary tables. You can see the package contents by querying `user_source`, `all_source` or `dba_source`, depending on which level you're viewing the data at.

The actual compiled version of the code that Oracle keeps is, as far as I know, an internal thing that isn't available to be queried in the dictionary tables.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that source code is being present in data dictionary only.
I wanted to know how it manages compiled version and how it tracks when any of the components used is invalidated.

Comment: Again, it's all tracked in the dictionary tables. How the Oracle code chooses to do that is not shared with us end users.